# After Retrieving data from a web page, MS Access does not update the table with the new values

Tags: xml, vba, http, ms-access

I designed a form to pull dates from my company webpage, I can change the dates and then it will update the dates in my company's page. This works like a charm.
If I push the button to retrieve the same information, the dates displayed will be OLD dates, not the new ones. I checked the webpage and the dates were put in place. If I close Access and reopen it, and verify the dates, ONLY THEN it will show the changes I made.

What am I missing?

```
Sub tbl50_UpdateModemDates() 'Retrieve the modem listed in the table and update the Delivery date, keeps the difference days between Preconfig, Loadout and Deliver dates

    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
    Dim URL As String
    
    Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
      
    Dim ModemStatus As String
    Dim MyRTBL50 As Recordset
    
    Const GETModemURL = "http://tanwebs.corp.halliburton.com/pls/log_web/mobssus_vieword$order_mc.QueryViewByKey?P_SSORD_ID="
        
    Set MyRTBL50 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl50_UpdateModemDateAutomatically", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    'Empty the table, keep the modem number only
    btnEmptyTable_Click
        
    While MyRTBL50.EOF = False
        
        ModemNr = MyRTBL50![ModemNr]
        
        URL = GETModemURL + ModemNr
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = RetrieveModemViaGETMethod(URL)
        ModemStatus = HTMLBody.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(19).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
    
        MyRTBL50.Edit
        
        If ModemStatus = "Activated" Or ModemStatus = "Not Activated" Or ModemStatus = "Ready" Then 'Retrive the data for each colum
            'Set maintable = HTMLBody.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0)
            'Set trcollection = maintable.getElementsByTagName("TR")
            Set trcollection = HTMLBody.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0).getElementsByTagName("TR")
            
            For Each tditem In trcollection
                            
                Select Case tditem.getElementsByTagName("TD")(0).innerText
                                
                    Case "Sales Order:"
                        'ZSPO
                        MyRTBL50![ZSPO] = tditem.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText
    
                    Case "Rig Name:"
                        'RigName
                        MyRTBL50![Rig] = tditem.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText
                    
                    Case "Well Number:"
                        'WellName
                        MyRTBL50![Well] = tditem.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText
                        
                    Case "Well Section:"
                        'Section Size
                        MyRTBL50![Section] = tditem.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText
                        
                    Case "Pre Config Date:"
                        'Preconfig
                        'MyRTBL50![PreConfigDate] = tditem.getElementsByTagName("TD")(1).firstChild.Value
                        MyRTBL50![PreConfigDate] = HTMLDoc.getElementById("P_DATE_LOAD").Value
                        a = HTMLDoc.getElementById("P_DATE_LOAD").Value
                                            
                    Case "Loadout Date:"
                        'Loadoutdate
                        MyRTBL50![LoadOutDate] = tditem.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText
                        
                    Case "Deliver To Customer:"
                        MyRTBL50![DeliveryDate] = tditem.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText
                    
                End Select
            If ModemStatus = "Ready" Then
                MyRTBL50![Comment] = "Modem Ready. Changes are not allowed."
            End If
            Next
        Else
            MyRTBL50![Comment] = "Skipped: modem already completed or canceled."
            
        End If
        
        MyRTBL50.Update
        MyRTBL50.MoveNext
        Refresh
    Wend
    
    MyRTBL50.Close
    Set MyRTBL50 = Nothing
    
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set HTMLBody = Nothing

End Sub
```

And the visualization for the form. The values that should display correctly are the 3 dates on the middle, after they are updated and I click the button Retrieve Modem Dates.

[image]

Thank you!
Sergio

Comment: What is the line `Refresh` supposed to accomplish? AFAIK, it does nothing. Do you have `Option Explicit` in module header?

Comment: I used that when I was developing the code and wanted to see the table being populated. It could definitely be just above the MyRTBL05.close. The refresh shows each line being populated. But I don’t think it interfere to display the data because another sub empties the all the cells prior to retrieve the new values from the website. I do t use any explicit declarations.

Comment: I have `Option Explicit` in every module. I tested `Refresh` and that triggers "variable not declared error".

Comment: At this moment I found the issue. I load a page from MS Access and update the page. To see the changes in Access, I need to use internet explorer and refresh the page I updated. Back to Access, it will display the new values. How do I clean the web cache which MS Access is using to refresh? If I close the database and reopen, it displays the changes I made as well, so I believe there is something I could do from Access side. I changed the OPTION WEB Services cache, but it didnt fix my issue.

Comment: Did you do any search? See if this helps https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?440508-Clear-IE-Browser-Cache-and-History-with-VBA

Comment: Thanks June7, I found the same article you shared. It is one option, but I dont want to touch the IE, instead, Access has its cache that avoids the data to be updated and it is cleared when I close and reopen it. I still couldnt find how to reset or clear or bypass Access' cache. I enabled the option NEVER CACHE in File-Options-Current Database, but looks like it didnt work. It is strange...